# React-Image-Gallery Resulting in Buggy Behavior

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, carousel

I've been trying to implement the `react-image-gallery` from [this npm package](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery).

While I'm able to get a few sliding images to work, whenever I click quickly on the next arrow button it pops up to the top of the screen in a buggy-like behavior:

[image]

I tried reducing the transition time in the CSS file, but the same glitchy behavior happens. What am I doing wrong and how can I get this carousel to have a consistently smooth transition like in the example?

I installed the package and then included it as recommended:

```
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import React from 'react'
import '../node_modules/react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const images = [
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/1/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/1/',
      },
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/2/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/2/'
      },
      {
        original: 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/nature/3/',
        thumbnail: 'http://lorempixel.com/250/150/nature/3/'
      }
    ]
    return (
      <ImageGallery items={images} />
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Did you ever try removing the image-gallery.css import?

Comment: This is not a buggy behaviour, Your images are taking time to load...use React.lazy/Suspense to handle this by lazyloading.